# Cannot access '@attributes' from JSON in PHP: "obj->@attribute"

Tags: php, json, syntax-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/JSON - stdClass Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754411/php-json-stdclass-object)

I have this JSON response:

```
{
    "findItemsIneBayStoresResponse": {
        "ack": "Success",
        "version": "1.12.0",
        "timestamp": "2012-11-09T17:14:20.543Z",
        "searchResult": {
            "@attributes": {
                "count": "1"
            },
            "item": {
                "itemId": "160884918999",
                "topRatedListing": "false"
            }
        },
        "paginationOutput": {
            "totalPages": "1",
            "totalEntries": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "entriesPerPage": "100"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the 'count' in '@attributes' with PHP. I thought `if ($decoded->findItemsIneBayStoresResponse->searchResult->@attributes->count > 1) {` would work, but I get the error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/ancienta/public_html/category.php on line 40`

What can I do?

Comment: That is commonly asked, use curly braces: `searchResult->{'@attributes'}->count` and you're fine. The other solution is to use `true` as second parameter for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode). You then access everything as an array.

Comment: Wow. Great, thanks! I tried EVERYTHING except those. Duh.

Comment: See my edited comment, there are two ways to solve that.

Comment: I see that.... didn't know I could do that either. That might come in handy one day. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the correlation, but I already got my answer anyway. ;)

Comment: The correlation is that like accessing a number as property, e.g. `->1` the @ does not work, too.

Comment: I fail to see how it's a duplicate of that question ..