# How to decode the Json Object in php - angularJs

Tags: php, jquery, json, angularjs, jsonp

Sending the Data from Angularjs in the form of JSON as below

Object {data: "stdClass Object↵(↵    [0] => B↵    [vin] => vin123…[value] => Gambia↵    [country_name] => Gambia↵)↵", status: 200, headers: function, config: Object}

Then in php how to access only the data in that Object Json 
   i.e data->0, data->vin etc...........

Comment: use the response of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754411/php-json-stdclass-object)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode) as it is a standard PHP function that transforms your serialized JSON object into a php array, that you then can use in php.

If you want an object representation, you may hydrate that object with data from that array.

Comment: i want the data from the Object, how to access it. Even we have status, header, config etc.. different properties is there. How to access data Only