# Json string reading

Tags: php, json, decode

ANSWER: [PHP/JSON - stdClass Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754411/php-json-stdclass-object)

I tried to read some statistics from a json like this, but I make a mistake somewhere. 
I tried with `foreach` function, but i don't know where is the mistake:

```
foreach($myDecodedStringFromJSon->playerStatsSummaries as $stats){
 // Do some here
}
```

This is my JSON:

```
{
   "summonerId":39656713,
   "playerStatSummaries":[
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType":"CAP5x5",
         "wins":0,
         "modifyDate":1431942577000,
         "aggregatedStats":{
            "totalChampionKills":3,
            "totalMinionKills":79,
            "totalTurretsKilled":0,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled":0,
            "totalAssists":4
         }
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI",
         "wins":22,
         "modifyDate":1431942577000,
         "aggregatedStats":{
            "totalChampionKills":73,
            "totalMinionKills":2344,
            "totalTurretsKilled":24,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled":0,
            "totalAssists":179
         }
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType":"OdinUnranked",
         "wins":0,
         "modifyDate":1431942577000,
         "aggregatedStats":{

         }
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType":"Unranked",
         "wins":18,
         "modifyDate":1431942577000,
         "aggregatedStats":{
            "totalChampionKills":63,
            "totalMinionKills":1789,
            "totalTurretsKilled":14,
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled":5,
            "totalAssists":181
         }
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType":"Unranked3x3",
         "wins":0,
         "modifyDate":1431942577000,
         "aggregatedStats":{

         }
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType":"AramUnranked5x5",
         "wins":38,
         "modifyDate":1445430660000,
         "aggregatedStats":{
            "totalChampionKills":414,
            "totalTurretsKilled":28,
            "totalAssists":1556
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

EDIT:

```
stdClass Object ( [summonerId] => 39656713 [playerStatSummaries] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [playerStatSummaryType] => CAP5x5 [wins] => 0 [modifyDate] => 1431942577000 [aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( [totalChampionKills] => 3 [totalMinionKills] => 79 [totalTurretsKilled] => 0 [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 0 [totalAssists] => 4 ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [playerStatSummaryType] => CoopVsAI [wins] => 22 [modifyDate] => 1431942577000 [aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( [totalChampionKills] => 73 [totalMinionKills] => 2344 [totalTurretsKilled] => 24 [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 0 [totalAssists] => 179 ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [playerStatSummaryType] => OdinUnranked [wins] => 0 [modifyDate] => 1431942577000 [aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [playerStatSummaryType] => Unranked [wins] => 18 [modifyDate] => 1431942577000 [aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( [totalChampionKills] => 63 [totalMinionKills] => 1789 [totalTurretsKilled] => 14 [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 5 [totalAssists] => 181 ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [playerStatSummaryType] => Unranked3x3 [wins] => 0 [modifyDate] => 1431942577000 [aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( ) ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [playerStatSummaryType] => AramUnranked5x5 [wins] => 38 [modifyDate] => 1445430660000 [aggregatedStats] => stdClass Object ( [totalChampionKills] => 414 [totalTurretsKilled] => 28 [totalAssists] => 1556 ) ) ) )
```

Comment: could you provide `print_r($myDecodedStringFromJSon)` for us. But as far as i can guess you string was decoded as array `$myDecodedStringFromJSon['playerStatsSummaries']`

Comment: I get the answer by myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754411/php-json-stdclass-object

Comment: @George-Cristian Yeah, All you need is the json_decode(string, true); As that turns it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just decode the JSON and loop using the `foreach`. The below code will help you.

```
$result = json_decode($json);
  foreach ($result->playerStatSummaries as $stats) {
  echo 'Wins: ' . $stats->wins;
  echo '<br>';
}
```